# How to make react to wait until api data is retrieved when use fetch

Tags: reactjs

I have a function like this

```
function getWeatherInfoForFavCities() {   
     fetch(`https://api.weatherapi.com/v1/current.jsonkey=.....&q=${cityName&aqi=no`)
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(json => {
        setFavCitiesWeatherInfo(json);
     });
  }
```

How can I to make react to wait until api data is retrieved in this particular case ?

Comment: you can show a loader until you know for sure that ur data is ready.

Answer (score 1):

Declare your function as an async function and then call fetch with await.

```
    async function getWeatherInfoForFavCities() {
    // method body
    await fetch("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1")
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((json) => {
        // body
        console.log(json);
      });

    console.log("Completed");
  }
```

This completed message console log only prints when fetch is completed.

Sandbox Demo - https://codesandbox.io/s/agitated-khorana-qtsv6?file=/src/App.js

Comment: In order to use await it is required to define a function as async. Please check again and i also attached a sandbox demo with the updated answer

Comment: I don't get any error, but it doesn't wait until api data is retrieved.

Comment: @Elisei_01 I think there may be some mistake with your code. If you share your code with sandbox it will help to answer